# Editar texto guardado en tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Trato de entender como es posible obtener el contenido que guardo del editor tinymce, para después poder editarlo cuando vuelva a ingresar los datos, intente lo básico en cuanto a código, si guarda la información y se despliega correctamente en otras paginas, pero no puedo editar lo que guarda desde el `iframe`.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Opciones generales
    mode : "textarea_especifico",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor"
});

console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

tinyMCE.get('textarea_especifico').getContent()
```

Uso la versión 4.3 de tinymce. Si alguien sabe hacer lo que pido en otro wysiwyg, también pueden poner la forma en que lo hicieron para guiarme.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es que escriba algo en el editor, se guarde y a continuación se modifique lo escrito y guardado previamente con el editor, cierto?

Comment: si, eso es lo que espero

Comment: Y no puedes volver a imprimir el contenido a modificar en el área de texto del TinyMCE? O lo quieres modificar todo mediante código?

Answer (score 1):

Yo hice algo parecido con Tinymce con PHP, javascript y HTML, haber si te sirve:

Para el script de Tynmce

```
$('textarea.editable').tinymce({
    //Ruta del archivo
    script_url : '../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
    //El modo en que va a operar, normalmente se recomiendan textareas
    mode:"textareas",
    // Opciones generales
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins:"preview",
    // Las opciones del tema
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,preview",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true                        
});
```

Para guardar lo que exista en el textarea, simplemente lo pongo dentro de un form y con su boton de submit

```
<form name="formulario" id="formulario">
     <textarea class="editable"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" id="boton_ini" name="boton_ini" class="tbtnazul">Guardar</button>
 </form>
```

**Nota: Aquí depende de que tantas cosas quieres enviar.**

Ya despues , en el submit yo envió el contenido a una función php para actualizar el documento.

Por ejemplo para el proyecto que utilice con Postgresql

```
pg_send_query_params($conexiondb, 'UPDATE constancia SET constrech = $documento WHERE material = $id;', array($id, $documento));
$res = pg_get_result($conexiondb);
$codErr = pg_result_error_field($res, PGSQL_DIAG_SQLSTATE);
pg_free_result($res);
if($codErr !== null && $codErr !== ''){ return obtener_ErrorDB($codErr); }
return true;
```

Eso sería un ejemplo de como actualizar tu contenido y si lo quieres ingresar el contenido basta con imprimir una VARIABLE PHP con su consulta SELECT.

Comment: Una duda, a que te refieres con que depende de que tantas cosas se quieran enviar?

Comment: ok, no se si eso lo hace para poder editar el textarea o el iframe, pero en mi caso ocupo editarlo desde el iframe

Comment: @GuillermoNavarro Si, se supone que tu cargas el tynimice en un textearea(cargas el editor), esto es como si fuese un input text, ya de ahí lo guardas normal en una BD por ejemplo mediante un formulario, y cuando quieras volver a editar el contenido, imprimes el contenido con php, en mi caso.